# How to build wiring Pi on windows

Tags: raspberry-pi, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to build the cross environment for raspberry Pi to build binaries on Eclipse CDT for windows.

I got Wiring Pi for accessing GPIO, and I need to build binary of Wiring Pi on windows by using 'Windows toolchain for windows'. I already set it up on Eclipse, but I have never build Wiring Pi yet.

The error message is 'poll.h no such file or directory found'. It seems that include path was correctly set up when I installed 'SysGCC'.

Please tell me how to build Wiring Pi using Eclipse CDT on windows.

Comment: The following URL may show an answer for this question. But I'm not 100% sure because I didn't try it yet because of another problem. [link]( https://42nexus.com/index.php/rpi-articles/item/4-eclipse-cdt-configure-eclipse-project-for-raspberry-pi-cross-compile)

Comment: Now I aborted to build wiring Pi on windows.

Instead of that, I built it on Raspberry Pi itself, and got 'libwiringPi.so.2.31'. It seems to be a shared library. I need to build my application with this library on Eclipse as a cross compiling environment, but I don't know how to setup *.so file on Eclipse.
Somebody, Please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've got the solution!

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=126493

I built wiringPi on Raspberry Pi, and transfer 'libwiringPi.so.2.31' to windows. Then I tried this process, I could succeed in building my application!

The key was renaming 'libwiringPi.so.2.31' into 'libwiringPi.so'. But I don't know why.

I will search for building wiring Pi itself on Windows Eclipse environment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So before you are writing an application with wiringPi you should test if your installation was successful by testing it via a terminal.

`gpio read #pin-number`

to find out what pin-number you need there are many references on the internet.

If your installation is correct maybe look at [raspberry forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=56304)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've already confirmed that wiringPi could work on my Raspberry Pi by a terminal. But my main question is how I can develop my application on windows cross compiling environment.